# Flutter Firebase Get or Search Data Containing String

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I looked in many places, but I couldn't find a correct and precise solution, so I'm asking again. I have an application and this application has a search query that works like this under normal conditions.

```
ds = await _firestore
        .collectionGroup("Cars")
        .where("name", isEqualTo: widget.name).get();
```

In this usage, I can get car names that match exactly what I type of widget.name.

But I want to run a query like this. For example, there are car names in this style in my database: `Mercedes Sport`, `Bmw Sport`, `Audi Sport`, `Porsche`. When I type `Sport` in the search field, I want to get `Mercedes Sport`, `Bmw Sport` and `Audi Sport` data. Or when I type `orsch` I want to get `Porsche` data or when I type `Mer` I want to get `Mercedes Sport` data. In other words, I want to display the string data containing the string that I entered briefly in the search section and searched.

I need a proper solution that will correctly meet all of the requirements I have described.

Comment: Firestore does not offer substring queries as you require.  You will need another database for this.  Firestore can do prefix queries, though, as described in the first duplicate.  But its indexes aren't able to search for arbitrary substrings.

Comment: I know firestore can't do a lot of things directly but I thought maybe there was a way

Comment: There is no way.

Comment: and there has to be a way because a lot of people are using firebase and many end users can't type everything correctly while searching. if there is no solution, there is nothing to do, anyway, thank you for your answer, how do you suggest me to do something?

Comment: As I mentioned, you can use a different database, perhaps at the same time as Firestore.  A discussion on how to do this is too big for Stack Overflow.  I suggest posting to a discussion forum if you want to engage others with ideas.

Comment: all my code and my application is completely dependent on firestore so there is no way to use a new database. I think there are some 3rd party software that can be added as firestore plugin, can you recommend me to use them?

Comment: I suggest posting to a discussion forum to get ideas about alternatives.  Stack Overflow is not a discussion forum that accepts recommendations for software products.

Comment: This is the documented solution on how to add full text search to Firestore: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/search. As Doug said, it uses another database for the full-text search part. There are also some extensions that make this even easier. Search for "Search" in https://firebase.google.com/products/extensions for more

Comment: Since I have never used an extension of this style before, I hesitated to use it, but if it is not difficult to use, I will try.